# Copyright Laws - App Development

Tags: copyright

I have made an app which is published on an app store for £0.29. It is basically just the website embedded into the app with no actual added functionality. The real website's name is mentioned in the title in brackets like this Something Client (App Name). It is stated in the description that it is an unofficial app not endorsed by the company in any way. Could I get sued for this?

Comment: If there is no added functionality then what is the purpose of you app? Why would people pay for your app when they visit the website for free?

Comment: Not sure, but 14 thousand people and counting have bought it in the past month.

Comment: Are you using their logo?  Is there a chance that purchasers believe that it is their official app despite wording you may have put in the fine print of the description?

Comment: @Anonymous so you are talking about a possible lawsuit in the order of 4k+. Get a lawyer **now**, which is about 2 months too late.

Comment: And do not answer anyone's comments here that seek more information about your actual app or personal situation.

Comment: @jen, you are out of line here. I am NOT seeking information about the actual app or the OP's personal situation. I AM attempting to clarify the question, and also get them to see the underlying issues WRT the risk inherent in possibly using a similar appearance and functionality of a well known brand such that the consumer might be fooled into paying money by thinking it is the official version despite a small print disclaimer. There is a method to my line of questioning, and your thinly veiled criticism is a misplaced and completely inaccurate assessment of my intent.

Comment: The OP is perfectly capable of choosing what they decide share without your personal coaching, and it isn't your responsibility to police communication between members on this site. Please stop.

Comment: "I am NOT seeking information about the actual app or the OP's personal situation." — cool; then my comment does not apply

Comment: Don't play coy with me counselor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pure technical tool to open the website in an app is not copyright infringement. Every browser does it. The www wouldn't really work if it weren't for browsers. And it's not only the big one's, lots of products you have probably never heard of rely on being able to present publicly available information neutrally, as a tool, without association with the specific contents the user or service provider decides to see or share.

However, if the app copied a specific state of the website and instead of getting the data from their webserver like a browser, bundled the copied state it with the app, that would indeed be copyright infringement. I mean literally, they copied the files.

Even if it's not literally copying files, but simply function as a browser with a fixed address bar, using the name, logos or other IP may be protected by copyright and/or trademarks. And using such things to market your own product (for example the original "App Name" as a tag or title in an app store, so people will find the app when they search for the origina website) is a violation of many of those protections.

This might be a bit vague, but obviously I have no idea if or what an unknown other entity may or may not have concerning copyrights to or trademarks.

That said, copyright and trademarks give specific rights. If the app has a contract with the holder of those rights, allowing them the use, then all is fine.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. Would just removing the app name out of the title get me out of any potential hot water?

Comment: @Anonymous That is a question for a lawyer well versed in your juristiction, the rights holders juristiction and possibly the market places juristiction.